# Hibernate : keeping the compatibility for the aggregate functions in hibernate 3.2

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, aggregate

Recently I migrate my application from hibernate 3.1 to 3.2.
But I'm getting some cast exception when using aggregate functions (count, avg..).

So, I would like to know how to keep my code's compatibility wiht the new version of hibernate?
Like making some change in the config of the sessionfactory bean:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
        singleton="true">
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>
                    hibernate/mapping/Domain.hbm.xml
                </value>
                <value>
                    hibernate/mapping/EpAttributeDef.hbm.xml
                </value>
                <value>
                    hibernate/mapping/Activity.hbm.xml
                </value>
....
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                    org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
                </prop>

                <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">
                    org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">0</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dataSource" />
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is provided here:
https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/30527532/

So the class of the sessionFactory bean would be ClassicLocalSessionFactoryBeanHibernate31 instead of LocalSessionFactoryBean.